# which one is the most correct answer?

Tags: differences

i want to get a professional photographer to take my photo. which question is grammatically correct?

1. do you know where I can get a professional photographer take my
   photo?
2. do you know where I can have a professional photographer to take my photo?

I saw the difference is only "get" and "have" part. and also "to" in sentence 2. please tell me the true answer.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is actually:

> Do you know where I can get a professional photographer to take my
>   photo?

You want to use "get" with "to."

Answer (score 1):

The title of your post should be "more correct" and not "most correct," because you're choosing between only two.

"Get" and "have" are Causative Verbs and both of them can be used to express what you want. But here are their respective patterns:

> get + somebody + to Verb
>
> have + somebody + Base Verb

Because of this, both your sentences are wrong.

---

You can also avoid Causative Verbs altogether:

> Do you know where I can find a professional photographer to take my
>   photo?

In this particular example, you don't need to care about the Infinitive (to + Verb) anymore because it's not connected to any Causative Verb.

Comment: I really don't see what's wrong with 'Do you know where I can get...' 'Get' simply means 'obtain' here.

Comment: Hi. The issue isn't so much the Verb. I have nothing against it.  It's the absence of a word to connect the phrase "take my photo" in the OP's Example # 1. See above